# C# Form how to run method each time the keyboard key is press

Tags: c#, methods, console-application, keypress

My code is working perfectly in WindowsConsoleApplication

```
// The below code is working in WindowsConsoleApplication
class Class1
{
    public int a = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program prg = new Program();
            prg.hell(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Working" + prg.a);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    public void hell()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop");
            while
                (!Console.KeyAvailable || Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.DownArrow )
            { 
                a += 1;
            }
        }
}
```

But when i try to use the `hell` method in C# windows form throws an error

```
// This code isn't working in C# windows form
class Class1
{
    public int a = 0;
    public void hell()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop");
            while 
                (!Console.KeyAvailable || Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                a += 1;
            } 
        }
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1 obj = new Class1();
    MessageBox.Show("WORKING....");
    obj.hell();
    MessageBox.Show("Isn't Working...." + obj.a);
}
```

`obj.hell()` throws an error

> Cannot see if a key has been pressed when either application does not have a console or 
>   when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.In.Peek.

How can I solve this problem? And please try to compile the code to see whats going on, I tried threads but they aren't helpful. And working code will me more helpful then explanation. I tried the `Form1_KeyDown` as well, but it throws the same error.

Comment: You're not going to be able to write code that works in *both* a console app and a windows forms app, because the way that they model user input is *completely* different.

Comment: If you've branched out from Console apps to Windows applications (such as Windows Forms applications), it's time to learn about events, which is how all Windows applications work. That may require a new book.

Comment: "And working code will me more helpful then explanation." - Really?  An good explanation will help *you* much more in the long run.  Trust me =)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you the truth. Windows apps don't have a console, so you generally can't use any of the Console methods. To run a method each time a key is pressed in a Windows app, take a look at the `KeyPress` event on your Form object. I think you had the right idea, but make sure that the word "Console" does not appear anywhere in your event handler.